# is it possible to host a website from my computer with broadband

Tags: linux, website, broadband

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run Web Site From Home](https://superuser.com/questions/90721/run-web-site-from-home)

I am thinking about hosting a simple blog site from my PC. Is it possible to use broadband to host my site & how much minimum speed is required what are other necessary requirements to establish a web-server ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it's fully possible...in fact that is exactly what I do.  However, a couple of things to consider in addition to other answers:

- IP address.  If you can afford some downtime, Dynamic DNS may be an option but as new DNS entries propagate, users may not be able to access your site.
- Backups.  With a computer up and running 24/7, expect hardware failures.  I had a $2000 rack mountable server that worked for almost 10 years!!!  Now, I'm using a surplus machine from a company and there is no way I expect the same service time from it.  Backups, backups, backups.
- Backup Hardware.  Along the same lines, if/when the HW does fail you need to make sure you have a replacement ready to go.  Every hour you search for a new piece of HW is an hour users can't access your site.  Furthermore, make sure this backup machine is already installed, patched, and ready to go in the time frame you're willing have your site down.
- ISP allowing?  Many ISPs, especially those who serve up dynamic IP address do **NOT** want you to "serve up" anything.  Make sure you're not violating any terms or agreements that may get your service cut off at a moments notice.  If you choose to do so, all the risk and responsibility is on you.

Sorry if I scared you, but I hope you find this information useful.  Personally, it has been very rewarding having my own data on my own server.  I like having things the way I want it.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible?  Absolutely.  No question about it.  That's an answer to your first (and second) question.

How much minimum speed is required?  All depends on how much traffic you intend to generate.  The more people you get to your site, the faster your **UPLOAD** speed will need to be.  That's your third question.

What other necessary requirements to establish server?  Well now.  This just opens up a can of worms.

Let me step sideways.  Did you happen to search Superuser.com for this information BEFORE you asked your question?  You know... for the times that people asked the same question before you did?  How about some basic research with Google or another search engine?

here...

[Run web site from home](https://superuser.com/questions/90721/run-web-site-from-home?rq=1)

[Web Hosting at home on Old Hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/321145/web-hosting-at-home-on-old-hardware) (closed)

https://superuser.com/questions/373575/how-to-make-own-web-hosting-server-computer (closed)

[Hosting online with xampp?](https://superuser.com/questions/227146/hosting-online-with-xampp)

[Hosting a web site at home: ISP Blocking port 80?](https://superuser.com/questions/134905/hosting-a-web-site-at-home-isp-blocking-port-80)

Now, the closed ones are still there, they were just closed and are not accepting any further answers... for the reasons detailed on those pages.  And those are just 5.  See, when people ask questions here that have been asked before, the questions get closed as duplicates.  When people ask questions and show that they didn't do any basic research, their questions get downvoted... and usually closed.

The Internet is **FULL** of tutorials on hosting a web site/running a web server from your home connection.  So, you should go and search.  Read Tutorials.  Set one up.  And, if you run into a SPECIFIC problem, come on back and post that SPECIFIC problem, and we'll try to straighten you out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  The minimum speed will depend on what you put on the site and how fast you want things to load. If you host a site with mostly text and a few **small** pictures then just about any broadband will work fine.  if you use something will uses larger pictures or otherwise requires lager downloads then you will need to balance your upload speed with the patience of people visiting your website.

If you are going to host a website 24/7 then you might also consider a few other things, such as power used and noise generates by a PC which is always on.

If you usually turn of your PC when you go to work, then you might want to look at the price of a simple VPS vs power used etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will function as noted by @Hennes but some providers will block traffic on ports like 80, 443, 25 and many others.  as a result, users will be unable to access your site.  Check with your ISP or have someone test the ports.  Keep in mind that ISPs sometimes block after they detect the traffic.